# iphone HTML entities not interpreted

Tags: iphone, html, angularjs

I am currently working on a website for a client, who encounters a bug that even I am not able to reproduce...

Here is a page example : http://newsletter.thenextgag.com/#/5/2014-01-02

My client is using an iphone to navigate through the website and seems to encounter a realy weird bug : it looks like HTML entities are not interpreted, or that special characters are transformed into HTML entities and not showing correctly. Here is the image he produced to me : [image]

Do you have an idea ? I made some search but was unable to find anything on it..
I am using HTML5 and AngularJS, but I can't see why it should change anything..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you're using Angular 1.2.3 and the `linky` filter. There seems to be some [changes in 1.2.4](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#124-wormhole-blaster-2013-12-06) in `$santize`, that the `linky` filter uses, that affects [how it handles escaped/entity characters](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/81b81856ee43d2876927c4e1f774affa87e99707).

If you create an extremely simple page, with the following controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.content = "L\u2019appli iPhone de l\u2019ann\u00e9e. Qui n\u2019a pas perdu un ou des amis \u00e0 cause de leur addiction \u00e0 ces bonbons ?";
});
```

with a template:

```
<div ng-bind-html="content | linky"></div>
```

Then using Angular 1.2.3 on an iPhone (in my case, iPhone 4 running IOS 7.04), the output is:

> L&#8217;appli iPhone de l&#8217;ann&#233;e. Qui n&#8217;a pas perdu un ou des amis &#224; cause de leur addiction &#224; ces bonbons ?L’appli iPhone de l’année. Qui n’a pas perdu un ou des amis à cause de leur addiction à ces bonbons ?L’appli iPhone de l’année. Qui n’a pas perdu un ou des amis à cause de leur addiction à ces bonbons ?L’appli iPhone de l’année. Qui n’a pas perdu un ou des amis à cause de leur addiction à ces bonbons ?

But doing the same thing on Angular 1.2.4 results in

> L’appli iPhone de l’année. Qui n’a pas perdu un ou des amis à cause de leur addiction à ces bonbons ?

I'm testing using https://npmjs.org/package/http-server on a Mac, in case there are some other issues at work that means this can't be reproduced everywhere.

So my solution would be to change the version of Angular you're using to 1.2.4 or later.